# Displaying default values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the home page, all subjects should be displayed.  When the subject is clicked, their respective chapters has to be displayed.  For the first time, that is when the subject is not choosen, then chapters of subject id 1 has to be displayed. In the below code, should i have to call get_chapters() from index and make get_chapters() to return chapters or any other better way of doing it?

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

private $data = array();

public function index()
{       
    $this->load->model('subjects_model');
    if($query = $this->subjects_model->get_all()) {
        $data['subjects'] = $query->result_array();
    }       


    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
}



public function get_chapters($id=null) {

    $this->load->model("chapters_model");

    if(!is_null($id)) {
        $query = $this->chapters_model->get_where('chapters', array('subject_id'=>$id));
    } else {
        $query = $this->chapters_model->get('chapters');
    }

    if($query) {
        $data['chapters'] = $query->result_array();
    }

    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);      
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
public function get_chapters($id=null) {
    $this->load->model("chapters_model");

    if(is_null($id)) {
        $id = 1;   
    }
    $query = $this->chapters_model->get_where('chapters', array('subject_id'=>$id));

    if($query) {
        $data['chapters'] = $query->result_array();
    }

    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
}
```

If the `$id` is `null` then defaltly `subject id` will become `1` orelse it will search with the existing `subject id`

Comment: I thnk its beter to call it from index() function

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index($id=null) 

{

        $this->load->model("chapters_model");

        if(is_null($id)) {
             $id = 1;   
         }

        $query = $this->chapters_model->get_where('chapters', array('subject_id'=>$id));

        if($query) {
            $data['chapters'] = $query->result_array();
         }

        $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
}
```